# Is it possible to add custom css class to the buttons on a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, css, class, button

I am trying to write custom class in dialog box button. I am unable to do do that it is not taking custom css class at all.  My code is as follows:

```
function AddProcedures() { 
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg.status) {
            $("#modal_Window").dialog({
                title: 'XX',
                buttons: {
                    Close: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                open: function() {
                    //debugger;
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Close")').removeClass("ui-button-text-only");
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Close")').removeClass("ui-button-text-only").parent().addClass('ButtonLong');
                    $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Close")').addClass("ButtonLong");
                },
                modal: true
            });
            $("#modal_Window").html('MM');
        }
        error: function(msg) {
            ErrorDialog('@RelatedProcedure.ProcedureTitle', '@RelatedProcedure.Error');
        }
    });
}
```

I have spent one full day to do it. I may not expert in Jquery.  Please help me.

Comment: Please post html css or Create a fiddle and give me link

Comment: You appear to have an extraneous ) on the second-to-last line. You may want to check that you've posted all the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.  It worked for me. I just made four CSS group styles to style the buttons

```
button[type="button"].ConfirmButton 
button[type="button"].ConfirmButton:hover 
button[type="button"].CancelButton 
button[type="button"].CancelButton:hover
```

and this is the JavaScript:

```
var ModalDiv = $(document.createElement("div"));

$(ModalDiv).html('Are you sure you want to delete this note from the request?');

$(ModalDiv).dialog({
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    closeText: "",
    hide:{
              effect: "fade",
              delay: 0,
              duration: 250,
              easing: 'linear'
          },
    show: {
              effect: "fade",
              delay: 0,
              duration: 250,
              easing: 'linear'
          },
    width: 400,
    title: "Tile of Dialog",
    dialogClass: "ui-dlgconfirmation",
    buttons: [{
                  text: "Delete",
                  class: "ConfirmButton",
                  click: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              },
              {

                  text: "Cancel",
                  class: "CancelButton",
                  click: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                  }
              }]
});

With
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes simply while adding button,add the class name

```
Close   : {

              class: 'yourNewClassname', click: function() {

               //on click

            },
```

Comment: I have tried ur code It is giving MS Visual studio error (80020101) from line (t&&g.test(t)&&(e.execScript||function(t){e.eval.call(e,t)})(t) ) under Jquery-1.8.3.min.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the css styles by like the css below

```
#popupid .ui-button-text-only{
 . . . . 
. . .  . .
font-size:14px;
. . . . 
. . .  . .
}
```

you can use the button id or class for specify conditional css

Answer (score 0):

you can override css styles with jQuery or javascript.

Just try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('theTargetedIdentifier').css({'font-size':14});
});
```

Comment: I am using Modal Dialog Box in MVC3 using Jquery.